# Remove extra data from get_data string

Tags: php, get

I am now having a problem with get_data. The website that i used before returned the result in plain text but now they have "" around the result. How do I get rid of them.

```
 add_filter( 'mycred_buycred_get_cost', 'adjust_buycred_points_cost', 10, 4 );
 function adjust_buycred_points_cost( $cost, $amount, $prefs, $buy_creds ) {
 $dogeprice1 = $amount * (get_data('https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price'));
 $roundedprice = (number_format((float)$dogeprice1, 2, '.', ''));

 return $roundedprice + 2.50;
 }
```

Expected Result would be 0.00111617 instead of "0.00111617"

Comment: please mention expected result from get_data()

Comment: Show your result & expected result.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic but who the hell builds a wallet service around the doge-meme?

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar 0.00111617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = strlen($dogeprice1);
$result = substr($dogeprice1,1, $str-1);
```

This will removed the first and last chareter. I guess it will work for you.

Comment: That does not change anything

Comment: Try replacing the substr with mb_substr

Comment: Just to make sure im not the one messing up here can you write it in to the code i gave you above.

Comment: replace this: get_data('https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price') by $result

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    If you need get_current_price
  add_filter( 'mycred_buycred_get_cost', 'adjust_buycred_points_cost', 10, 4 );
 function adjust_buycred_points_cost( $cost, $amount, $prefs, $buy_creds ) {


    $data='https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price';  //here you set the url
    $url_val=explode('=',$data);
    $url_price=$url_val[1];

 $dogeprice1 = $amount *$url_price ;
 $roundedprice = (number_format((float)$dogeprice1, 2, '.', ''));

 return $roundedprice + 2.50;
 }
```

This will give value of 'a' in url

Comment: Still cant get it to work. Please try writing it in to my code to see if im making the mistake.